# sencha touch 2.2.1 check if store is empty from controller?

Tags: controller, sencha-touch, store

how can I achieve the above please? I have a nested list retrieved as a json file from a server. When there is data, I want to show the list, otherwise I need to display a message to the user such as "No Data currently Available"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use option emptyText in List config to display message. http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List

```
var nestedList = Ext.create('Ext.List', {
   emptyText : 'No Data currently Available',
   store : store
});

store.on('load', function(store, records) {
    if (records.length == 0) {
        nestedList.getActiveItem().setHtml(nestedList.getEmptyText());
    }
});
```

Full example here http://www.senchafiddle.com/#2WiFV

Comment: Thanks but I am afraid that this will not work in 2.2.1 as written here [http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?269939-EmptyText-attribute-is-not-working-in-Ext.dataview.NestedList] I need to do it from the controller on store load.

Comment: Oh... I just saw your answer... And it is like mine.. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it as follows after reading the docs... In the controller, I wrote:

```
init: function() {
     var onlineStore = Ext.getStore('OnlineStore');

     onlineStore.on('load', function(store, records) {
         if (records.length == 0) {
                 list.getActiveItem().setHtml('<p>No data available!</p>');
         }
     });

 }
```